# Missing WIFI driver on ASUS X551MA laptop

Tags: wireless, drivers, laptop, hardware

The WIFI does not seem to work by default, and I cannot seem to find any resource online. Where would I start looking?

Output of lshw looks as follows

```
ubuntu
    description: Notebook
    product: X551MA (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: E7N0CX295495298
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=X sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=11000000-0000-0000-0000-7824AF71EC4C
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: X551MA
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: X551MA.510
          date: 06/27/2014
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB
             vendor: Hynix Semiconduc
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0B2DF00B
             slot: A1_DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber1
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
             physical id: 1
             serial: A1_SerNum1
             slot: A1_DIMM1
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 12
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 112KiB
          capacity: 112KiB
          capabilities: internal write-back
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 13
          slot: CPU Internal L2
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2830  @ 2.16GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 14
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2830 @ 2.16GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 2158MHz
          capacity: 2400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 83MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: ValleyView SSA-CUnit
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0e
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: ValleyView Gen7
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:106 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f080(size=8)
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:104 ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f050(size=8) ioport:f040(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:d0815000-d08157ff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 0e
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:103 memory:d0800000-d080ffff
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: Encryption controller
             product: ValleyView SEC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:d0500000-d05fffff memory:d0400000-d04fffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 0e
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:107 memory:d0810000-d0813fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: ValleyView PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: ValleyView PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 memory:d0700000-d07fffff
           *-network
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:d0700000-d0707fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: ValleyView PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:d0600000-d06fffff
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Unassigned class
                product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d0600000-d060ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
                logical name: eth0
                version: 06
                serial: 78:24:af:71:ec:4c
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:105 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0614000-d0614fff memory:d0610000-d0613fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: ValleyView Power Control Unit
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: ValleyView SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 0e
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:d0814000-d081401f ioport:f000(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST500LT012-1DG14
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0003
             serial: S3P629JM
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=d249ab9a-2fae-4930-b982-8ae340dab7e1 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 4678-a6f6
                size: 95MiB
                capacity: 99MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI system partition
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 180a-5752
                size: 894MiB
                capacity: 899MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-05-04 18:16:59 filesystem=ntfs label=Recovery name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: reserved partition
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: 741d25f8-9bd3-4026-b122-89f8e5dc06e6
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 3.1
                serial: 1cf80e29-0c84-d644-a7bf-5c058690830b
                size: 186GiB
                capacity: 186GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-05-04 18:17:04 filesystem=ntfs label=OS name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: 6c583a8d-52b5-764d-8f95-9dc41297a86f
                size: 131GiB
                capacity: 131GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-08-13 16:49:12 filesystem=ntfs label=Data modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:5
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                version: 1
                serial: 3958a59e-e583-45dd-8143-e98654a2c3bc
                size: 3982MiB
                capacity: 3982MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
           *-volume:6
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 3.1
                serial: 6411-6204
                size: 20GiB
                capacity: 20GiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-05-04 18:17:10 filesystem=ntfs label=Restore modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          bus info: usb@1:1
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SE-208DB
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             logical name: /cdrom
             version: TS01
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime state=mounted status=ready
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /cdrom
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime signature=094a46d6 state=mounted
              *-volume UNCLAIMED
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   version: FAT12
                   serial: 20e8-7ecd
                   size: 15EiB
                   capabilities: primary boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          bus info: usb@1:2
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             size: 14GiB (15GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=0008a6b1
           *-volume
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /media/ubuntu/KINGSTON
                version: FAT32
                serial: 3195-501b
                size: 14GiB
                capacity: 14GiB
                capabilities: primary fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=KINGSTON mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=999,gid=999,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
```

The Network part of it is

```
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0.2
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
    logical name: eth0
    version: 06
    serial: 78:24:af:71:ec:4c
    size: 10Mbit/s
    capacity: 100Mbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
    resources: irq:105 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0614000-d0614fff memory:d0610000-d0613fff
```

Comment: output of `lspci -vnn | grep Network`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: How did you get ubuntu to boot after installation? I tried several fixes found in the forums and was unsuccessful every time. I have tried Ubuntu 12-15, Mint 13-15, and even Kbuntu 14-15, and while they will all install none are able to boot once installed, they get stuck at "recovery" in the bios. And yes, UEFI is fully enabled.

Comment: I didnt manage to boot after installing until i completely removed windows. It seems window will take precedence, ruining dual boot

Answer (score 1):

for the wireless you have, it's

> Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

You might need to install the proprietary driver for it.

Please connect to the Internet by using the Ethernet port (for download the driver), and open your dash, search for "driver, you will see a tool for this:
[image]

Select the driver, press "apply changes"
[image]

It should do the trick. (Although this is demoed on 14.04, it could apply to 12.04 too)